# Why my file directory cannot be found after deploying the project thru a war file

Tags: java, file, deployment, war

I deployed a Java EE project thru a .war file and now it's uploaded online but the new File("directory") is missing. How to properly set the path of a file?
The current path is at

```
"/home/jebard/chabacano/Chabacano1/src/en-pos-maxent.bin"
```

Comment: I mean; The POS Tagger model file does not exist! Path: "/home/jebard/chabacano/Chabacano1/src/en-pos-maxent.bin"

Comment: Have you checked that physical path, does it exist?

Comment: Yes , on the localhost it is working

Comment: Yes, that we know. But presumably that directory doesn't exist where-ever you uploaded your application. Why would you assume it would?

Answer (score 0):

After deploying your application can't access to your file system, it has an access only to content of .war file. So, to get access to some file you have to include it to .war archive while building.

Comment: Not true. There is no reason why the web server cannot access the file system. Whether it _should_ or not is another issue. And hopefully file permission would prevent the web server from looking where it shouldn't - but that would be a different error.

Comment: If so, how can i do it? @Everv0id